# pandaslooping through grouped data for a plot

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I did the following:

```
for grp, val in df_grp:
    ax1.plot(val.concentration,val.capacity,'o', label = grp)      
ax1.set_xlim(0,2.5)
plt.legend(loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=[0,0,1.5,1])
```

How do i get rid of the brackets, the 'u' and the quotation marks ?

[image: Result from plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the groups as labels, the labels are actually the `str` property of `tuple` representing each group, a quick work around:

```
In [42]:

print df
  v1  v2  v3
0  A  11   1
1  A  11   2
2  A  30   3
3  A  30   4
4  B  45   5
5  B  45   6
6  B  12   7
7  B  12   8
In [43]:

ax = plt.subplot(111)
for grp, val in df.groupby(['v1', 'v2']):
    ax.plot(val.v3,val.v3-1,'o', label = grp)
L = ax.legend(loc=4)
_ = [item.set_text(' '.join(map(str, eval(item.get_text())))) for item in L.get_texts()]
```

[image]

Show it step-by-step:

```
In [38]:

[item.get_text() for item in L.get_texts()]
Out[38]:
["('A', 11)", "('A', 30)", "('B', 12)", "('B', 45)"]
In [39]:

[eval(item.get_text()) for item in L.get_texts()] #convert them back to tuple
Out[39]:
[('A', 11), ('A', 30), ('B', 12), ('B', 45)]
In [41]:

[' '.join(map(str, eval(item.get_text()))) for item in L.get_texts()] #into strings
Out[41]:
['A 11', 'A 30', 'B 12', 'B 45']
```

Comment: +1 for giving me a better understanding of python and for this nice answer

Comment: but what does the underscore ?

Comment: `.set_text()` method returns `None`. So if you are using interactive environment the last step is going to return `[None, None, None...]`, `_=` suppress that output.